# Counting between two different tables Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have two ORACLE tables, FOLDER and FILES. Each folder contains several files.
I am trying to get the number of files for number of folders. The number of folders x that contains the number of files y.
For example 50 folders contain 10 files, 35 folders contain 8 files...
Can I get some help please on the query :

select count(fl.id_folder) ,count(fi.fileID) from FOLDER fl inner join FILES fi on fl.id_folder=fi.fileID group by fl.id_folder;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the query using group by as follows:

```
Select cnt_files, count(1) as num_of_folders
from
(select fl.id_folder, count(fi.fileid) as cnt_files
  from FOLDER fl 
  Left join FILES fi on fl.id_folder=fi.fileID
Group by fl.id_folder)
Group by cnt_files;
```

**Note:** I have used the `LEFT JOIN` to consider all the folders (With and Without files in it)

Comment: The query gives the count of each table. but I am seeking the query to determine that we hav 50 folders of category containing 20 files. we have 40 folders containing 35 files etc...

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two levels of aggregation. Assuming that table `files` has a column called `id_folder`, you would do:

```
select cnt_files, count(*) cnt_folders
from (
    select count(*) cnt_files
    from files 
    group by id_folder
) t
group by cnt_files
```